# Normalização de banco de dados com 'serviços pais' e 'serviços filhos'

Tags: banco-de-dados, normalização

Estou modelando uma base de dados que serviços pertencem a uma categoria (utilizado na maioria dos casos). Atualmente, as categorias são definidas na propria tabela de serviços com uma flag 'nivel' onde eu digo se aquele registro é 'pai' ou 'filho'.
Nesse caso, essa seria a forma correta de modelagem de categorias de serviços?

Exemplo atual:

```
codigo | cod_pai | nivel  | nome  
 0001  |  0001   | pai    | Acessórios  
 0002  |  0001   | filho  | Item de Acessórios  
 0003  |  0001   | filho  | Item de Acessórios  
 0004  |  0001   | filho  | Item de Acessórios
 0005  |  0005   | pai    | Mesa e Banho
 0006  |  0005   | filho  | Item de Mesa e Banho
 0007  |  0005   | filho  | Item de Mesa e Banho
```

Comment: Sim, com essas informações é possível achar o filho, pai, avô e assim por diante. O principal é fazer um bom algorítimo para recuperar as informações necessárias.

Answer (score 3):

A terceira forma normal (3FN) busca eliminar valores reduntantes nos dados de uma aplicação. No seu caso, a informação da coluna `nivel` é reduntante, já que pela própria coluna `cod_pai` você fica sabendo se aquela coluna possui uma categoria pai ou não.

Na verdade, o certo seria que a coluna `cod_pai` fosse `NULLABLE` – dessa forma, uma tupla que não possui esse valor é a categoria pai, e as tuplas que possuem esse valor são as categorias filhas (e potenciais categorias pai).

Seu modelo ficaria dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Além de seguir a recomendação do @Rodrigo Rigotti, de deixar o campo `cod_pai` como `Nullable`, também colocaria um coluna `Id` se pesquisar pelas categorias via SQL for ser uma operação comum. Este Id seria preenchido via trigger para facilitar as consultas e montagem de caminhos / arvores.

A forma mais fácil é ir concatenando o `id` do registro pai com o `codigo` da seguinte forma

```
codigo | cod_pai | id     | nome  
 0001  |  null   | 1.     | Acessórios  
 0002  |  0001   | 1.2.   | Item de Acessórios  
 0003  |  0001   | 1.3.   | Item de Acessórios  
 0004  |  0001   | 1.4.   | Item de Acessórios
 0005  |  null   | 5.     | Mesa e Banho
 0006  |  0005   | 5.6.   | Toalhas de Banho
 0007  |  0005   | 5.7.   | Toalhas de Mesa
 0008  |  0007   | 5.7.8  | Toalhas de mesa redondas
```

Dessa forma, ao pesquisar por todas as categorias filhas de **Mesa e banho**, poderia utilizar `WHERE cod_pai = 0005` se quisesse somente as categorias ou `WHERE id LIKE '5.%'` se quisesse pesquisar em subcategorias.

> **PS:** Note que não foi criado um Id sequencial, visto que o objetivo não é exibição pelo cliente e apenas uma organização lógica e simples das categorias

Comment: Hoje existe o id @Caputo. Apenas coloquei um resumo.

Comment: Ok @RafaelSoufraz, vou deixar a resposta apenas como um exemplo então, já que é uma informação pertinente ao modelo. Obrigado pelo feedback

Comment: Já sobre a concateção, já tive más experiencias com ordenação de registros concatenados. Tive que usar inet_atom do mysql. Não achei lá uma boa prática. Mas valeu a dica. Toda informação é bem vinda. :)